# Is there a way to configure php heredoc variable substitution?

Tags: php, variables, substitution, heredoc

I regularly use the [PHP HereDocs and NowDocs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to add large strings of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS content to my code, but I sometimes run into situations where I want to have a PHP variable's value substituted into a HereDoc string that also contains jQuery code, which causes errors/problems when the **$** prefix  for jQuery conflicts with the **$** prefix for the PHP variable's name.  This situation only gets worse when I prefix JavaScript object variables that are assigned jQuery Objects because I indicate this by prefixing the JavaScript variable name with a **$**, i.e., **$*variable-name***.

Is there a way to configure PHP to only substitute variable values when it 'sees' a variable specified as **${*variable-name*}** instead of **$*variable-name***?  This way the PHP compiler won't produce an error when it can't find a PHP variable for the jQuery statement that follows the **$** or cause problems when it substitutes my jQuery statement or JavaScript variables for a PHP variable that happens to exits?

When I use a HereDoc, I explicitly use double quotes around the opening identifier to make it clear that I'm going to specify a PHP variable in the string that will have its value substituted into the string, i.e.:

```
$statement = <<<"STATEMENT"...${phpVar}...STATEMENT;
```

I realize that the default action of a HereDoc is to allow substitutions and explicitly enclosing the identifier with double quotes just makes it easier to differentiate the HereDoc from a NowDoc statement, and that enclosing a php variable in curl-braces only makes the variable easier for me to see the PHP variable amongst the rest of the text in the string.

I use NowDocs to prevent the unwanted substitutions or to make the compilation faster.

However, I'm looking for a way to make variable substitution only happen when I explicitly use double quotes in my HereDocs and curl-braces around the PHP variable.

To get around situations where I need to use jQuery and PHP variable substitution in the same text string, I break my HTML/JavaScript/CSS into chunks and enclose them in HereDocs and NowDocs, but this makes reading my code much harder.

If it isn't possible to make **${*php_variable*}** the only way to cause variable value substitution rather than $*php_variable* in HereDocs that explicitly use double quotes, then how can I submit this as an enhancement request to the PHP Development Organization?

Thanks

Comment: won't escaping jquery `$` inside your HEREDOCs work? E.g. `\$.ajax({...`

Comment: Thanks, berend, but apparently no, the compiler output Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Controller\...Controller could not be converted to string when it encountered \$.ajax( .  Too bad, because the escape trick worked for all of the $ prefixed variables and other jQuery statements before this line.

Comment: Oddly, when I change \$.ajax( to jQuery.ajax( in my HereDoc I get the same error, so it wasn't the \$.ajax statement, but just the use of any \$ escapes, is my guess.  So, again, apparently, no.  To bad there isn't some way to pre- and post- process a HereDoc while compiling a PHP script.  In the prepress step I would change $ that weren't followed by a { into something else, then let the compiler find the ${...} as it processed the HereDoc, and then postprocess the HereDoc to change the 'something else' back to $, so that JavaScript would 'see' them and work normally.

Comment: Is the PHP's language structure extendable, as some scripting languages are, so that new reserved words and functionality could be added to the language, such as <<$ for a new kind of HereDoc that ignores $ unless followed by a {.  Actually this would be a nice jumping place to implement PHP function calls within the ${...}.